# In ElasticSearch is it possible to sum a non-indexed field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field that is a numerical value. I never need to search on it or filter on it, so it is not indexed.
Is there any way to aggregate this field?

The code below doesn't work. `total_profits` is always zero.

```
            "aggs": {
                "by_day_count": {
                  "date_histogram": {
                    "field": "purchase_date",
                    "calendar_interval": "1d",
                    "time_zone": "Asia/Tokyo",
                    "min_doc_count": 1
                  }
                },
                "by_day_count2": {
                  "date_histogram": {
                    "field": "purchase_date",
                    "calendar_interval": "1d",
                    "time_zone": "Asia/Tokyo",
                    "min_doc_count": 1
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "gross_sales": {
                      "sum": {
                        "field": "total" <-- indexed, works fine.
                      }
                    },
                    "total_profits": {
                      "sum": {
                        "field": "total_profit" <-- non-indexed field
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
```

Comment: There just *might* be a way to do it. Can you share some docs and the relevant parts of your index mapping?

Comment: it's weird because numeric fields are aggregatable no matter whether indexed or not. Can you provide your mapping?

Comment: Turns out I hadn't added the field to my mappings! You can put data into ES (and get it out) without having the field in the mappings. That's what tripped me up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a non-issue.

The problem was not that ElasticSearch can't aggregate non-indexed fields. The issue was that I had not added the new field into the mappings! In case anyone else has this issue, be aware that you can send data to ES (and get it back out again) without it being in the mappings. But you won't be able to do anything with it in a query.